# Writing $a_n$ for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose if we have a pattern like this
$$1=1^3$$
$$3+5=2^3$$
$$7+9+11=3^3$$
and so on.................

I want to know how do I write any $nth$ row in terms of $\sum$ notation?

**MY work:**

I have figured out that the first term of the each row is of the form $$n^2-n+1$$ and then every row is having a sequence with + 2 with preceding term till n value which can be written as 
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} n^2 - n+1+2j$$

How to write summation for whole expression? ? Is it possible to write it in single summation ???

Can we write it using double summation also ?
**Expression the whole equation in summation notation both the sides**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $n$-th row is then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (n^2-n+1+2k).$$

Comment: wrong ,  where is the nth value verification equation ??? i want both sides

Comment: I did not read that in your question, you only seem to ask about the left summation side.

Comment: @learningstudent I understood your question exactly as Dasherman did. Please edit your question to clarify what you really want.

Comment: what he have formulated i have the a_n already as i mentioned  the +2 thing but my concern is how to get the whole equation